# UNREGISTER_FIELD does not update syncErrors

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using redux-form for my wizard and I have some fields which can be shown/hidden depending on some other fields value. When they are rendered they are required but of course if they are hidden validation should be avoided.
I noticed that in the case when they are first shown (and required) and then hidden, `UNREGISTER_FIELD` is called but the `syncErrors` is not updated and still includes as invalid the field which has just been unregistered; this is the action

```
{
  type: '@@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD',
  meta: {
    form: 'registerAccommodationForm'
  },
  payload: {
    name: 'property.breakfastPrice',
    destroyOnUnmount: false
  }
}
```

and this is this state (which has not changed):

```
 form: {
    registerAccommodationForm: {
      syncErrors: {
        property: {
          breakfastPrice: 'Required'
        }
      },
```

My form is initialized in this way:

```
FormPropertyDetails = reduxForm({
  form: 'registerAccommodationForm',
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
})(FormPropertyDetails);
```

Is this a normal behavior? Shouldn't the validation be updated when fields unregister? How could one trigger an update of `syncErrors` when dynamic fields are shown/hidden?
I'm using version 6.7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I just needed to add `forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true` in form initialization:

```
FormPropertyDetails = reduxForm({
  form: 'registerAccommodationForm',
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
})(FormPropertyDetails);
```

In this way the state of my wizard is preserved but fields values and `syncErrors` are cleared when a field is unmounted. You can find a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oQ2J8OwPY)

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for sharing your answer here. Am running redux-form 7.4.2 and was encountering the syncerrors not clearing out after unregistering the field. Adding the forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true solved my issue as well.